# Select to get data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

My table structure

```
id     name 

1      bhagi
1      user
1      amit
1      sumit
2      bhagi
2      chinmay
2      sumit
3      rashmi
3      RBS
4      sumit
4      amit
4      bhagi
4      rashmi
4      RBS
```

I want result

```
id     name     result

1      bhagi    1/4(position of bhagi for id 1(1) / no of time that id is present(4))
1      user     2/4
1      amit     3/4
2      bhagi    1/3
2      chinmay  2/3
3      rashmi   1/2
4      sumit    1/5
4      amit     2/5
4      bhagi    3/5
4      rashmi   4/5
```

My requirement is to get the result column

Example: for Id 1

There a re 4 id present bhagi,user,amit and sumit

for bhagi the result would be 1/4(because position of bhagi is 1 in the db and no of id 1 present is 4)
similarly for others

and i want to ignore when result is 1.

i tried but don't know to to calculate the denominator part. means the no of times the id is present.

[EDIT]

I have tried

```
 select id,
   name,
   IF(@LAST=(@LAST:=id), @CURROW := @CURROW + 1, @CURROW:=1) AS ROW_NUMBER
 FROM FEEDBACK_STORE 
 JOIN (SELECT @CURROW := 0, @LAST:=0) R
```

its giving result

```
id    name   row_number

1     bhagi    1
1     user     2
1     amit     3
1     sumit    4
2     bhagi    1
2     chinmay  2
2     sumit    3
3     rashmi   1
3     RBS      2
4     sumit    1
4     amit     2
4     bhagi    3
4     rashmi   4
4     RBS      5
```

i need the denominator part only the count of id eg: for id 1-4 , for id 2-3,for id 3-2,for id 4-5

[/EDIT]

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a homework!! what you have done so far?

Comment: no no this is not my homework.

Comment: i don't want to use sub query

i can solve this problem with sub query

can you Please solve this using single query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery to calculate the number of rows with the same id and a smaller or equal name:

```
select  t1.id
,       t1.name
,       concat(
        (
        select  count(*)
        from    Table1 t2
        where   t1.id = t2.id
                and t2.name <= t1.name
        ), '/', total.cnt)
from    Table1 t1
join    (
        select   id
        ,        count(*) as cnt
        from     Table1
        group by
                 id
        ) as total
on      t1.id = total.id
order by
        t1.id
,       t1.name
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b091/5/0)

Or, with the faster but dirtier variable trickery:

```
select  t1.id
,       t1.name
,       concat(
            if(@last=(@last:=t1.id), @cur:=@cur+1, @cur:=1),
            '/',
            total.cnt)
from    Table1 t1
join    (
        select @cur := 0, @last:=0
        ) r
join    (
        select   id
        ,        count(*) as cnt
        from     Table1
        group by
                 id
        ) as total
on      t1.id = total.id
```

[Also at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b091/9/0)

Comment: Sorry i don't want to use sub query

and your query gives wrong result

it is giving amit 1/4 that should be bhagi 1/4

Comment: Rows in a SQL table do not have a defined order.  It's only an `order by` clause that can guarantee ordering.  The order rows appear in without an `order by` can change after a restore, an index reorganize, or even a MySQL version upgrade.